# Join de tablas A y B, con una sub consulta en la tabla C

Tags: sql, subconsultas, informix

Necesito mostrar los datos de la tabla A (lote), que tienen 10 registros en la tabla B (lotecargado), siempre y cuando en la tabla C (transporta) el atributo fechahorafinal esté vacío. Es de aclarar que la tabla lote tiene como clave primaria ´id_lote´, que es foránea en las otras dos como ´lote´. 
Mi intento de filtrar eso es el siguiente:

```
SELECT id_lote, 
       COUNT(lote) 
FROM lote 
LEFT JOIN lotecargado
ON id_lote = lote 
WHERE id_lote = ALL (SELECT lote FROM transporta
WHERE fechahorafinal is null) 
GROUP BY id_lote 
HAVING COUNT(lote) = 10 
ORDER BY id_lote
```

Y al momento en las pruebas debería devolver 1 fila, pero devuelve cero, 
quitándole esta parte: `WHERE id_lote = ALL (SELECT lote FROM transporta
WHERE fechahorafinal is null)`, devuelve las 2 filas que tengo, pero una tiene cargada una fechahorafinal y la otra no.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

#### En español (traducido por Google):

No debe usar una LEFT JOIN entre `lote` y`lotecargado` para las condiciones establecidas, y también puede usar una unión entre `lote` y`transporta`.

```
SELECT A.id_lote, COUNT(*)
  FROM lote AS A
  JOIN lotecargado AS B ON A.id_lote = B.lote
  JOIN transporta  AS C ON A.id_lote = C.lote
 WHERE C.fechahorafinal IS NULL
 GROUP BY A.id_lote
HAVING COUNT(*) = 10     -- HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10?
 ORDER BY A.id_lote
```

---

*In English:*

*You should not be using a LEFT JOIN between `lote` and `lotecargado` for your stated conditions, and you can use a join between `lote` and `transporta` too.*

```
SELECT A.id_lote, COUNT(*)
  FROM lote AS A
  JOIN lotecargado AS B ON A.id_lote = B.lote
  JOIN transporta  AS C ON A.id_lote = C.lote
 WHERE C.fechahorafinal IS NULL
 GROUP BY A.id_lote
HAVING COUNT(*) = 10     -- HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10?
 ORDER BY A.id_lote
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.
pregunta 1: por que el cambio del having count(lote) por el count (*)? si bien la tabla tiene 3 atributos, y uno de ellos el ´lote´ es el que se puede repetir, afecta que solo cuente la columna ´lote´?
pregunta 2: si necesito saber que cuenta exactamente 10 para cada ´lote´ y que el sistema trunca en 10 y comienza con un nuevo lote, por que la sugenrencia "--HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10?" ?
De nuevo gracias, pero quisiera entender éstas dos cosas.

Comment: Traducido por Google: Porque es poco probable que marque la diferencia y es más convencional. El uso de `COUNT(lote)` cuenta el número de filas no NULL; usando `COUNT(*)` cuenta todas las filas. Como no hay una LEFT OUTER JOIN, no hay valores NULL (espurios) en los datos. ——— _(In English: Because it is unlikely to make a difference and is more conventional.  Using `COUNT(lote)` counts the number of non-NULL rows; using `COUNT(*)` counts all the rows.  Since there is no LEFT OUTER JOIN, there are no (spurious) NULL values in the data.)_

Comment: Traducido por Google: El SQL no se ha probado porque no hay datos de muestra en la pregunta y no tuve tiempo para crear un esquema equivalente y algunos datos de muestra. No debería tener que hacer eso. ——— _(In English: The SQL is untested because there is not sample data in the question and I did not have time to create an equivalent schema and some sample data.  I should not have to do that.)_

Comment: Igualmente gracias. Por encontrarse trabajando con la DB completa un compañero, no tengo como hacer la prueba ahora, pero de lo poco que se, creo que va por buen rumbo.